# Filter the exact match from the django query set

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, filter

I have gearbox_model values like this in the queryset in Django

```
gearbox_model = 'XLG , SG'
```

I have values arrays and I want to filter these values from the query set

```
values = [ 'LG', 'SG']
```

So , I annotate the query set to create the gearbox_model_array

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(gearbox_model_array=SplitComma("gearbox_model"))
```

the gearbox_model_array becomes like this

```
gearbox_model_array = [ 'XLG' , 'SG' ]
```

Then I do filtering

```
for value in values: 
    queryset = queryset.filter(gearbox_model_contains=value)
```

The issue is __contains returning the substring matches as well . For example the record gearbox_model_array = 'XLG , SG' returns as the substring 'LG' exist in it. I Also tried

```
queryset = queryset.filter(gearbox_model_array__iexact=[value])
queryset = queryset.filter(gearbox_model_array__in=value)
```

using the these above Got exception

```
django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal: "LG"
LINE 1: ...productmanagement_pump"."gearbox_model", ',') IN ('LG')) sub...
```

I want to filter the exact the values from the gearbox_model_array not want to match the substring.

Comment: Can you show the models as well a some sample values?